# How to avoid global vars (/abuse of builtin): Sharing data between modules/classes (Python3)

Tags: python, oop, scope, global-variables, interactive-shell

I wish to have an interactive shell that allows me to perform data manipulation using a series of modules defined in my package. For example, I want to be able to type:

```
$ Input('data.csv')
$ GroupBy('key')
$ Output('data.csv')
```

Where `Input`, `GroupBy` and `Output` are all modules/classes of my package that implicitly operate on some 'global' `data` iterator. The easy way to do this would be to explicitly pass `data` as an argument, but I want the control over what happens to `data` to be in the background (maybe I'm distributing it across compute cores and map-reducing, without the user knowing).

This is the closest I've got so far:

```
class env(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.data = []
            code.interact(local=locals())

    def __iter__(self):
            return self.data

    def run(self, className, *args, **kwargs):
            c = globals()[className](*args, **kwargs)
            self.data = chain(self.data, c)

    def __getattr__(self, attrName, *args, **kwargs):
            return partial(self.run, attrName)
```

Then within my package `__init__.py` I instigate `env`.  My `env.py` will then import the rest of the package modules into it's own namespace (for example `Input`, `GroupBy` and `Output`), which let's me do:

```
$ self.Input('data.csv')
$ self.GroupBy('key')
$ self.Output('data.csv')
```

So close, but I want to get rid of the `self`!

I thought what I could do was make my `env` class inherit from `dict`, and then do `code.interact(local=self)`, but sadly this does not seem to work?

Please tell me how to achieve this in a Pythonic way (or explain why what I'm trying to do is not Pythonic and offer an alternative), otherwise I'm going to be very naughty and add `data` to `builtins` so I can access it globally across modules...

tl,dr; How do I wrap all of my package's modules within a class that controls access to global data?